# Input field masking in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, masking

**This is my input field section**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="accountNumber">Account Number <span class="validate_star">*</span></label>
        {!! Form::text('acc_number',isset($bank_details)? $bank_details->acc_number: old('acc_number'),['class'=>'form-control ac_no','placeholder'=>'Enter Account Number', 'id'=>'accountNumber']) !!}
    </div>
```

**I want  to show the account no in a format like 'XXXXXXX8675'..but the data never change**

Comment: You can use Regular Expressions JS to formate your input.

Answer (score 1):

Your last input will be visible to 4 digits

```
var word = "12345678675";

function mask() {
  if (word.length <=4) {
    return word
  } else {
    var masked = word.substring(0, word.length - 4).replace(/[a-z\d]/gi,"X") + 
    word.substring(word.length - 4, word.length)
    return masked;
  }
}

console.log(mask(word));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can format the input value using regex
Try this :

```
(?=\d{5})\d
```